# Get object from controller to view using ajax in .net mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Teacher teacher = teacherService.GetTeacherById(id);
            EditTeacherData(teacher);
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult EditTeacherData( Teacher teacher)
        {
            return Json(teacher);
        }
```

Ajax:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Teacher/EditTeacherData",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (response) {
                debugger;
                alert('eror');
            }
        });
```

View:

```
@model StudentTeacher.Models.TeacherViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EditTeacher";
}

<h1>EditTeacher</h1>

<h4>Teacher</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="AddTeacherForm">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="TeacherId" id="TeacherId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" id="Name" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Designation" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Designation" class="form-control" id="Designation" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Designation" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Education" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Education" class="form-control" id="Education" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Education" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="JoiningDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="JoiningDate" class="form-control" id="JoiningDate"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="JoiningDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit"  value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

teacherService is a service that retrieves data that match with id. But it return null object. When I use this  EditTeacherData(teacher); ajax not return a null object But in debugger model show value takes this function. I just wanna get an object through ajax and show data in the field via ajax.

Comment: Show your view code, so we could map the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is no parameter passed in to the controller in your ajax, so `Edit` method will never receive the parameter passed in.

You can implement it with `EF core`. If you want to use `ajax`, you can refer to [this](https://codinginfinite.com/crud-operations-asp-net-core-mvc-tutorial/).

You can also achieve it `without ajax`, it much easier, please refer to [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-learn-crud-operations-in-entity-framework-core-from-zero-to-hero/).

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending data from your ajax request. Please [read this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for clear understanding

```
$('#Submit').click(function(){
  var formData = $('#AddTeacherForm').serialize();
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Teacher/EditTeacherData",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert('eror');
        }
  });
})
```